# ファイルの読み込み時のエラーの解決策がわからない

Tags: julia

コマンドプロンプトからファイルを読み込む際にエラーが起きます。

```
include("c:\\Users\\name\\desktop\\test.jl")
ERROR: LoadError: syntax: invalid character "."
Stacktrace:
 [1] include at .\boot.jl:317 [inlined]
 [2] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1044
 [3] include(::Module, ::String) at .\sysimg.jl:29
 [4] include(::String) at .\client.jl:392
 [5] top-level scope at none:0
in expression starting at c:\Users\name\desktop\test.jl:71
```

このcharacter"."というのがどこのことを指しているのかわかりません、しかも読み込むコードはほかのエディタでは問題なく動くのですが。。読み込む際のエディタはメモ帳で行っています。
メモ帳(test.jl)の中身

```
function run(itr)
    n = 27
    c0=zeros(Int,nthreads())
    c1=zeros(Int,nthreads())
    c2=zeros(Int,nthreads())
    c3=zeros(Int,nthreads())
    c4=zeros(Int,nthreads())
    c5=zeros(Int,nthreads())
    @threads for i in 1:itr
        walk = zeros(Int8,n,n,n)
        walk[1,1,1]=1
        for t in 0:3600
            next_walk = zeros(Int8,n,n,n)
            number=rand(UnitRange{Int8}(1:6))
            if t==0
                c0[threadid()] += 1
            else
                for x = 1:n, y = 1:n, z =1:n
                    x1 = ((x-1 + (n-1)) %n) + 1
                    x2 = ((x+1 + (n-1)) %n) + 1
                    y1 = ((y-1 + (n-1)) %n) + 1
                    y2 = ((y+1 + (n-1)) %n) + 1
                    z1 = ((z-1 + (n-1)) %n) + 1 
                    z2 = ((z+1 + (n-1)) %n) + 1
                    if Stage[x,y,z]== 0
                        continue
                    else
                        if walk[x,y,z]== 0
                            continue
                        else
                            if number == 1
                                if Stage[x2,y,z]==1
                                    next_walk[x2,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                else
                                    next_walk[x,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                end
                            elseif number == 2
                                if Stage[x,y2,z]==1
                                    next_walk[x,y2,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                else
                                    next_walk[x,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                end
                            elseif number == 3
                                if Stage[x,y,z2]==1
                                    next_walk[x,y,z2]=walk[x,y,z]
                                else
                                    next_walk[x,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                end
                            elseif number == 4
                                if Stage[x1,y,z]==1
                                    next_walk[x1,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                else
                                    next_walk[x,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                end
                            elseif number == 5
                                if Stage[x,y1,z]==1
                                    next_walk[x,y1,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                else
                                    next_walk[x,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                end
                            elseif number == 6
                                if Stage[x,y,z1]==1
                                    next_walk[x,y,z1]=walk[x,y,z]
                                else
                                    next_walk[x,y,z]=walk[x,y,z]
                                end
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end
            　　walk = copy(next_walk)
            #println(t,walk,"\n")
            if t == 2 && walk[1,1,1]==1
                c1[threadid()] += 1
            elseif t == 4 && walk[1,1,1]==1
                c2[threadid()] += 1
            elseif t==6 && walk[1,1,1]==1
                c3[threadid()] += 1
            elseif t == 16 && walk[1,1,1]==1
                c4[threadid()] += 1
            elseif t==36 && walk[1,1,1]==1
                c5[threadid()] +=1
            else
                continue
            end
            end
        end
    end
    println("t=0:",sum(c0),"\n","t=2:",sum(c1),"\n","t=4:",sum(c2),"\n","t=6:",sum(c3))
    println("t=16:",sum(c4),"\n","t=36:",cum(c5))
end
```

Comment: おそらく転記の際のミスかと思われるのですが、`@threads for i in 1:itr` は `Threads.@threads for i in 1:itr` ですよね？

Comment: いえ、ちがいます。このサイトを参照しました。https://qiita.com/goropikari/items/dc9ceddfb2d92a744e25

Comment: juliaのターミナルであらかじめ並列計算を使うためのセットアップはしております。

Comment: 了解です。ところで、test.jl の71行目には `U+3000`(いわゆる「全角スペース」)が入っていますが、これを ASCII のスペース文字(`0x20`)に置き換えるとどうなるでしょうか？

Comment: 少し話がそれてしまって申し訳ないです、今、julia環境が少しおかしいことに気づいたので、確認がとれない状況になっています。

Comment: わざわざ、コマンドターミナルから呼ぶ必要がなく、エディタ上（jupyter notebook）から上のプログラムを走らせることで解決しました。

Answer (score 0):

上のプログラムに加えて先頭に
using Base.Threads()
using Benchmark.Tools
などを加えるだけで解決しました。
ただ走らせる前にコマンドプロンプト上で
set(macならexport)JULIA_NUM_THREADS = スレッド数
としてから>Julia→>using IJulia>notebook()としました